An English word for "visible side". (cooking term)

Put the flour paste in the frying pan and bake it. When the visible
side of it starts to firm, flip it over.

(My sentences.)
My intuition tells me that no native speakers of English would use visible side. What word would you use instead of it?
At first, I thought it was a "face", but it seems to be used for coins.

Replace "bake" (implicitely in the oven) by "cook". Then the "visible side of it" is simply the "top".

No, we would say: Place the flour paste [rice cake or what??] in the frying pan until it firms up. Also, bake is in the oven, not on a stove top.

Also not asked for, but "flour paste" is often "batter" (if it's liquid enough to pour) or "dough" (if it's solid enough to shape by hand). I'm guessing batter is best since you talk about it "firming." (Also: "firm" as a verb is not wrong, but it's a bit more common to use it as an adjective along with a verb like "get firm" or "become firm." As a verb, it often pairs with "up": "When the top starts to firm up, flip it over." This isn't a very formal usage, but fine for a recipe.)

I had completely forgotten the word "batter". Thank you very much, Andy Bonner.

I think your intuition is correct and native speakers of English would not use 'visible side'… and that being so, where did this phrase come from, please?

"Visible side" is my English translation of the Japanese phrase "見える面".

I'd call it the "top". The "bottom" is touching the surface of the pan. When you flip it over, the sides are reversed.
Even if it is flat like a pancake, the 'sides' could be mistaken for the edge. Certainly, when cooking a steak in a frying pan there are techniques to sear the edges, so the top and bottom of a steak would never be called that.

Thank you very much, Astralbee. Do both "the top" and "the top of it" work in my sentence?

@Kaguyahime "of it" is fine but not necessary. "When the top starts to..." has the same meaning.

There are some problems with the sentence. It's already been pointed out that flour paste may be interpreted as batter, but it may not be clear to everyone. Another issue is that when you fry something in a pan, it gets heated from the bottom. So, the top of the pancake wouldn't firm in the pan. The bottom side gets firm first, and the top is still uncooked. Cooks can judge when the pancake is ready to be flipped by intuition and by lifting one side up gently.
When you bake something in an oven, first of all, not all frying pans are safe for oven use. Second, you are getting heat from all directions, although there is more heat from the bottom since the baking tray (or whatever piece of cookware) heats up. You can toss things halfway, like french fries being reheated, but I don't think we would flip things like, say, cookies.

You wouldn't use "firm up" for the bottom side though - that "crisps" or, i dunno, "cooks"?

The point is, the topside does firm up, just a bit, gelling into something firmer than raw batter

It seems that "topside" has a completely different meaning in British English. https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/topside?q=topside
